# how to slow down the speed of buffer sending java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, buffer, java-server

I have a server and i want to slow it down for some reasons and for experiments

```
long length = fileToSend.length();
            byte [] longBytes = new byte[8];
            ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(longBytes);
            bbuffer.putLong(length);
            connectionSocket.getOutputStream().write(longBytes);

            BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedInputStream bain = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToSend));

            byte buffer [] = new byte [1024];
            int i = 0;
            while((i = bain.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0){

                bout.write(buffer, 0, i);

            }
            System.out.println("chunk sended");
            bout.close();
            bain.close();
```

i have some thoughts using something like thread sleep! but i don't now if it is sufficient and good solution! can someone guide me how to do that

Comment: As to whether `Thread.sleep(L)` is sufficient, why don't you try it?

Comment: Please use a [throttling proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/) instead of changing your code to adhere to a bandwidth limitation. It is much easier to configure / re-configure.

Comment: but if i want to do it inside my java server?

Answer (score 0):

Using the thread.sleep(0.500); seems to work right! but is any other good solution to test it? or something else could be better?